# Need help to show the following is valid in SD+

Tags: logic

I have to rely only on SD+ rules

I use the Logic Book.

Show that the following is valid in SD+

Derive Y=Z

1.~Y-> ~Z. Assume

2.~Z->~X.  Assume

3~X->~Y. Assume

I got Z->Y but am stumped on getting Y->Z

I tried everything.

**I request any help or hints in finishing it**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the contrapositive.  Y->X, X->Z, therefore Y->Z.  (you can show this follows by assuming Y and using modus ponens).